# Applying the same function across columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am applying an ML estimate of a Bernoulli random variable. I have initially the following code:

```
muBern = 0.75;
bernoulliSamples = rand(1, N); 
bernoulliSamples(bernoulliSamples < muBern) = 1;
bernoulliSamples(bernoulliSamples > muBern & bernoulliSamples ~= 1) = 0;
bernoulliSamples; % 1xN matrix of Bernoulli measurements, 1's and 0's

estimateML = zeros(1,N);
for n = 1:N
    estimateML(n) = (1/n)*sum(bernoulliSamples(1:n)); % The ML estimate for muBern
end
```

This works fairly well, but every run of the code is only one possible result of taking `N=100` observations. I want to repeat this experiment `I=100` times and take the average of all the results, to get a solution that accurately represents the experiment.

```
muBern = 0.75;
bernoulliSamples = rand(I, N); 
bernoulliSamples(bernoulliSamples < muBern) = 1;
bernoulliSamples(bernoulliSamples > muBern & bernoulliSamples ~= 1) = 0;
bernoulliSamples; % IxN matrix of Bernoulli measurements, 1's and 0's

estimateML = zeros(I,N);
for n = 1:N
    estimateML(n,:) = (1/n)*sum(bernoulliSamples(1:n,2)); % The ML estimate for muBern
end
```

I am wondering if this `for` loop is doing what I want it to: each row represents a completely different experiment. Is the second code instance doing the same thing as the first one, only with 100 different results as a cause of 100 different experiments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any loops. In the single-experiment case, replace the loop by this, which does the same thing:

```
estimateML = cumsum(bernoulliSamples) ./ (1:N);
```

In the multiple-experiment case, use this:

```
estimateML = bsxfun(@rdivide, cumsum(bernoulliSamples,2), 1:N);
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with the answer, I was just overthinking it, if anyone is interested the following is what I was looking for:

```
for n = 1:N
    estimateML(:,n) = (1/n)*sum(bernoulliSamples(:,1:n),2); % The ML estimate for muBern
end
```